# How do I reference an HTML id using a link in an SVG File?

Tags: html, css, svg, href

For example, in the HTML I have a id="section1"

and in the SVG I have an href="#section1" on a circle I can click. At the moment, this takes me to svgname.svg#section1 rather than htmlpagename.html#section1.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Edit:

Circle in SVG that i've linked:

```
<a
id="a295"
class="js-scroll-trigger"
href="#portfolio">
<ellipse
onclick="#portfolio"
class="scroll-down"
fill="#ffffff"
fill-opacity="0"
id="path3905"
cx="726.10693"
cy="731.57501"
rx="24.696276"
ry="24.81061" /></a></svg>
```

How i've referenced it in HTML:

```
<embed class="nopadding scroll-down" src="img/homepagefinal7.svg" 
style='width:100%;display: block;' />
```

where i want it to scroll to:

```
<section id="portfolio">
<div class="wow fadeIn container-fluid" style='font-family:"Baskerville"; margin: auto;'>
<!-- Portfolio  -->
<div class="row">
...
...
...
```

thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: To be clear, i want to move to that part without reloading the page, otherwise i would href the index.html#section1

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code, its hard to figure out what is wrong without it because the way you describe the problem seems like it should be working

Comment: I've added the code, thank you! :)